# Grails: How to delete a record from a many to many relationship?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0

App Info:

- Grails Version: 3.1.8
- Groovy Version: 2.4.6
- JVM Version: 1.8.0_60

My domain class:

```
class AgePhase {

    String agePhase

    static hasMany = [assessors: Assessor]
```

Other domain class:

```
class Assessor {

    static belongsTo = [AgePhase]

    static hasMany = [agePhase: AgePhase]
```

In my database I have the Assessor, AgePhase and the join assessor/agePhase table.

How do I delete a record from the assessor/agePhase table based on the agePhase ID and the Assessor ID?

Comment: Isn't it as simple as `Assessor.findAllByAgePhase(AgePhase.get(agePhaseID))*.delete()`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the `removeFrom` on the `AgePhase` object (because it has the belongs to this class) and give an Assessor object as argument.

**Example:**

```
def agePhase = AgePhase.get(agePhaseId)
def assessor = Assessor.get(assessorId)

agePhase.removeFromAssessors(assessor)
```

This will delete the entry in the jointable of agePhaseId and assessorId

Answer (score -1):

If you want to delete a record from the relational table based on the **agePhaseId** and the **assessorId**, you can try the following:

```
def agePhase = AgePhase.get(agePhaseId)
def assesor = agePhase.assessors.find{ it.id == assessorId }
agePhase.removeFromAssessors(assesor)
```

Reference in Grails documentation: [removeFrom](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.8/ref/Domain%20Classes/removeFrom.html)

Comment: to call find on all assessors is bad style because you query all assesors in the database.